# Why is my React Component not updating according to its state value here?

Tags: reactjs

Here's my setup:

```
var PageController = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            'activePage': null,
            'saved': [],
        };
    },  
    savedRoutes: function(){
        return (
            <div className="viewContainer">
            {
                this.state.saved.map(function(route) {
                    console.log('ROUTE', route.destName) // ROUTE PRINTS OUT A STRING HERE
                    return 
                        <div className='favouritedRoute'>
                            <div>Destination: {route.destName}</div>
                            <button>Go!</button>
                        </div>
                })
            }   
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Where the `route` has just been pulled in from a rest-point.

However, in the line I emphasized above, route ALWAYS is a valid object with a `destinationName`, however that entire bit within the `.map` never seems to get rendered!

`this.state.saved` does not change after it gets the result. In addition, from the console, I forced updates of the component, but nothing seemed to happen, even though when I directly accessed the state variable, it was clearly valid.

What's going on here?

Comment: We might need a bit more code to see whats going on. Are you using setState to modify the state or are you directly modifying the state variable? Where is your render function?

Comment: There's nothing here about how you're actually setting the state, so we can't really tell what's wrong.

Comment: where's your call to `setState`, and where's your `render()` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript’s ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) rule at work. Whenever you see a `return` statement continued on the next line, be wary, for JavaScript will insert a semicolon there. In particular, your code is changed to this, where it returns nothing and leaves dead code:

```
return;
<div className='favouritedRoute'>
    <div>Destination: {route.destName}</div>
    <button>Go!</button>
</div>;
```

Solution: don’t break a line there.

Comment: Crazy, wouldn't even know what to look for had you not pointed that out. Thanks for this.